# mysql command line thinks I am using a different table. ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database called maxppgco_drp1 with a table called users.  I want to update the users table.

```
mysql --user=maxppgco --password=myPass -D 'maxppgco_drp1' -e "SELECT * FROM maxppgco_drp1.`users` WHERE 1";
```

the error I get is:

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'maxppgco_drp1.maxppgco' doesn't exist
```

How do I properly select the table.  The query works in PHPmyAdmin.

**EDIT::::Solution::::**

```
mysql --user=maxppgco --password=myPass -e "USE maxppgco maxppgco_drp1; SELECT * WHERE 1";
```

Need to choose database in sql -e statement with USE statement.. not in the command line with -D

Comment: Does the `[client]` section of your option file contain any [`execute`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) or [`init-command`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_init-command) entries?  Perhaps try specifying [`--no-defaults`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_no-defaults) to be sure?  Failing that, is the server configured with [`init_connect`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect)?

Comment: Or, is `maxppgco_drp1.users` a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html) that references `maxppgco_drp1.maxppgco`?  Please paste the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE maxppgco_drp1.users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,`mysql --user=maxppgco --password=myPass -D 'maxppgco_drp1' -e "use maxppgco_drp1;SELECT * FROM maxppgco_drp1 WHERE maxppgco_drp1.'users' = 1";`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your table is not called maxppgco.users but maxppgco. Users is probably a column that is part of your WHERE cause.

In one statement `mysql --user=maxppgco --password=myPass -D maxppgco_drp1 -e "SELECT * FROM maxppgco_drp1 WHERE maxppgco_drp1.users = 1";`.

Or perhaps breaking up the statement works.

1. Login with your username / password (`mysql --user=maxppgco
   --password=myPass`) or (`mysql -u maxppgco -p`).
2. Type in your password "myPass".
3. Connect to you database maxppgco_drp1 (`connect
   maxppgco_drp1`).
4. Execute your SQL statement (`SELECT * FROM
   maxppgco_drp1 WHERE maxppgco_drp1.'users' = 1`).